# How can I update a column with new values in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called nyc which consist 3 columns , id , geom and area.Geom column is of type geometry. I want to calculate the area of each geom in the table and it to area column of nyc table.

I tried using the below command but it did not work:

```
update nyc as p set area=(select st_area(geom) from nyc) where p.id=nyc.id;
```

It give me an error saying:

```
LINE 1: update nyc as p set area=(select st_area(geom) from nyc...
                                       ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Since id is unique column I assume that I should update the column based on id. I am little confused how could I update the values in a row.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is `id` the primary key?

Comment: Yes is a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is the primary key, you don't need any sub-select:

```
update nyc
   set area = st_area(geom);
```

This will update all rows in the table, replacing the existing value of the `area` column with the new one.

Comment: Can you tell me why don't we need a where clause here? Is it safe to use a where clause? If so How can I include it in this query

Comment: @johnmathew: I can't tell you if you need a where clause. You should know. Do you want to update all rows? If yes, then no where clause is needed. If you only want to update specific rows, then you need a where clause that only selects those rows. But you are the only one who knows that.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write your `UPDATE` statement to something like below

```
update nyc as p 
set area = tab.new_area
from (
select id, st_area(geom) as new_area from nyc
) as tab 
where p.id = tab.id;
```

Comment: Hi , it says tab.id does not exist.

Comment: @johnmathew, that's cause I didn't included it in inner query. Check now.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a join or a sub-select here